# Condiciones del if no funcionan (PHP)

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi página me redireccione a una página de error en caso de NO SER 2 páginas específicas:

Lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente:

```
$carrito = "/carrito";
$order = "/order";
$error = "/error";
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($currentpage != $carrito || $currentpage != $order|| $currentpage != $error) {
    header("Location: /error");
}
```

Si la página actual NO ES "carrito", "order" o "error", entonces redireccionar a la página error (agrego también la página error porque sino se crearía una redirección infinita).

Esto no funciona. Si yo dejo solamente una condición (ejemplo carrito) funciona correctamente, y me muestra la pagina de carrito y las otras redirecciona a error (aunque no se visualiza porque se crea la redirección infinita "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS").

¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcionen las 3 condiciones? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dice @Vlady, tendrías que usar `AND`, o, si quieres simplificar, puedes crear un array con las URLS permitidas y verificar ese array contra `$currentpage` mediante el uso de [**`in_array()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php). Así te evitas usar `N` variables y `N` comparaciones.

```
$allowedList=array("/carrito","/order","/error");
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (!in_array($currentpage,$allowedList)){
    header("Location: /error");
}
```

Y, si mañana necesitas meter otra(s) URL en la lista, sólo la agregas al array y el código no tendría que ser modificado en ninguna otra parte:

```
$allowedList=array("/carrito","/order","/error","/nueva");
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (!in_array($currentpage,$allowedList)){
    header("Location: /error");
}
```

Comment: La cuestión sería al revés, tener una lista blanca y que el resto de páginas sean todas lista negra, igual es muy util tu respuesta, muchas gracias.

Comment: @GabrielBenitez para una lista blanca sería casi lo mismo, creas tu array de direcciones y haces el `if` en afirmativo: `if (in_array($currentpage,$whiteList)){ //redireccion  }`

Comment: sabes que estoy probando el código y en realidad funciona como una lista blanca sin cambiar nada, ya que redirecciona cuando la página NO ES $blacklist, y si fuera una lista negra debería redireccionar cuando la pagina ES $blacklist. Me es muy útil tu solución, la voy a utilizar!

Comment: @GabrielBenitez para este caso tendría que ser así, porque `$currentpage` sería la URL actual, si lo haces al revés estarías redireccionando a la misma página. Para una lista blanca sería comparar en base a otras cosas, por ejemplo una petición que te hacen en una API y quieres controlar que los usuarios no escriban cualquier cosa, permitiendo solamente los puntos de entrada indicados en la lista blanca. Bueno, pensándolo bien, me equivoqué al considerar las URL del array como una lista negra, voy a darle una nominación más clara....

Answer (score 1):

Cambia los OR por AND:

```
$carrito = "/carrito";
$order = "/order";
$error = "/error";
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($currentpage != $carrito && $currentpage != $order && $currentpage != $error) {
    header("Location: /error");
}
```

Comment: Al parecer era tan simple como eso, a veces el "y" y el "o" se pueden interpretar de diferentes formas. Voy a probar a ver si funciona todo bien y te pongo como respuesta al problema.

Comment: Por algún motivo la pagina de error se queda en redirección infinita "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Error mío nomas, la respuesta resolvió el problema. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Deberías probar mejor con un .htaccess y pones adentro el siguiente código ->

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Sirve para decirle al servidor que si no encuentra alguna ruta, lo mande al error.php, así te evitas hacer tantas validaciones.

Comment: sucede que no quiero que redireccione a "error" solo cuando no encuentra una ruta, sino siempre que no se abra determinadas páginas que selecciono. Es una forma de bloquear todo el resto de páginas cuando no las quiero usar.